# Изменение структуры меню Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, menu

Не могу найти данные для редактирования структуры. Сейчас реализовано выпадающее вертикальное меню, и его нужно не много обыграть.

Пример того, как сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот пример, как нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственное, что я нашел в коде это в header.php -

```
    <div class="cat_menu">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light button" href="/catalog/"><span class="mdi mdi-menu"></span> Каталог товаров</a>
        <?php
                $args = array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'products',
                    'container'         => false,
                );
                wp_nav_menu( $args );
            ?>

    </div>
```

И в functions.php -

```
// Add menu support
add_theme_support('menus');
register_nav_menu( 'header', 'Главное меню' );
register_nav_menu( 'products', 'Продукты' );

// Menu classes ad active
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) || in_array('current-menu-parent', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: @kagg-design Здравствуйте, если вы еще раз прочтете мой вопрос повнимательней, вы увидите, что я никого не прошу написать мне этот код) Вопрос заключается в том, что надо найти код отвечающий за вывод меню, а как сделать дальше, думаю разберусь. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Сейчас вопрос сформулирован как раз так "и его нужно не много обыграть". Но ок. Вы нашли как раз тот код, который выводит меню. Фильтры типа `nav_menu_css_class` (есть и другие) позволяют в php добавить классы элементам меню. Но дальше вам придётся работать с css и js, чтобы кардинальным образом поменять выдачу меню и привести к виду на нижних картинках.

Comment: @kagg-design Так было написано для полного понимания сути вопроса, и примеры скинуты тоже, чтобы отсечь потом комментарии типа - а что у вас сейчас? Чего хотите добиться? А то, что "нужно обыграть", относится к моей задачи.
Фильтры добавляющие классы - понял, но мне же нужно сам код поправить, добавить вывод меню (ul) в div. Вот собственно и вопрос, где находится, фрагмент кода, который определяет каким образом будет обернуто меню. Но я так понимаю, вы предлагаете изменять меню с помощью добавлений и изменений кода через JS?

Comment: Нет, я этого не предлагаю. Структуру html надо менять с помощью php. Но в вашем вопросе ни слова нет про обёртку ul и прочее. Скажите конкретно, я примерами html, что во что надо превратить.

Comment: А css уже для наведения лоска. А js для реализации развёртывания плюсиков

Comment: @kagg-design На данный момент вывод категорий осуществляется вот так - 
`
<div class="cat_menu">
<a href="/catalog'>Каталог</a>
<ul id="menu_catalog">
<li id="menu_item">
<a href="/cat1">Категория</a>
<ul class="sub_menu">
...
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
`
Я собираюсь ul.sub_menu обернуть в div, для создания широкого блока с отображением уже подкатегорий. Надеюсь нормально объяснил, прошу прощения, если не так)

Comment: @kagg-design отображение подкатегорий при нажатии +/- уже сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вопрос свёлся к тому, как подправить при выводе некоторые элементы меню, то предлагаю использовать фильтр `wp_nav_menu_items`. Код примерно такой:

```
function wp_nav_menu_items_filter( $items, $args ) {
    $items_arr = explode( '<li ', $items );
    $new_items_arr = array();
    foreach ( $items_arr as $item ) {
        // Исправьте $item
        $new_items_arr[] = $item;
    }
    $items = implode( '<li ', $new_items_arr );
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wp_nav_menu_items_filter', 10, 2 );
```

В фильтр парметром `$items` прилетает строка с html-кодом меню, типа

```
<li id="menu-item-805" class="left-menu-cart menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-805"><a href="https://site.ru/cart/">Корзина</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-806" class="left-menu-user menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-806"><a href="https://site.ru/my-account/">Аккаунт</a></li>
```

С помощью explode я разбивал строку на элементы. Вам надо будет поступать аналогично с `<ul></ul>` и обрабатывать так, как вам это нужно.